# multiple versions of R in same ubuntu 14.04 machine

Tags: 14.04, r

Is there a way to have multiple versions of R co-existing in same Ubuntu 14.04 machine?

I would like to have R 3.0 but also 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3 in the same Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, but R has to be built from source for adding more versions. Detailed information from Rstudio can be found [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R). As I had the same problem today, I made a [shell script](https://github.com/DominikMueller64/install_R_source) for easy installation of multiple R-3.X.X versions on the same machine, which happens to be Ubuntu 14.04 in my case.